# Why does date is not working in azure when comparing with other two dates using javascript

Tags: javascript, azure, datetime, model-view-controller

I have three date fields:
1 - `From Date`
2 - `To Date`
3 - `DateOn`

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PeriodFrom, new { @class = "form-control form-control-user", type = "date", @min = "1900-01-01", @max = "9999-12-31"})

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PeriodTo, new { @class = "form-control form-control-user", type = "date", @min = "1900-01-01", @max = "9999-12-31" })

     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dateon, "{ 0:yyyy-MMM-dd }", new { @class = "form-control form-control-user", @min = "1900-01-01", @max = "9999-12-31", type = "date", @id = "dateOn" })
```

We first select From and To dates, then the `DateOn` field gets `From date` and once we click on the button it stores in the table and then increases the `DateOn` by 1 day till the `To date`.

It works fine in the local machine but it is not working when we send it to Azure.

Here is what I tried:

```
    var fromDate = "@(TempData["FromDate"] as string)";
     var toDate = "@(TempData["ToDate"] as string)";
                var sDt = new Date(fromDate);
                var onlyDate = sDt.getDate();
                var smonth = sDt.getMonth() + 1;
                var syear = sDt.getFullYear();
                var sD = 0;
                if (onlyDate <= 9) {
                    sD = '0' + onlyDate;
                }
                else {
                    sD = onlyDate;
                }
            sDateIs = syear + '-' + '0' + smonth + '-' + sD;
            $('#dateOn').val(sDateIs);
            var dtOn = $('#dateOn').val();
            var fromDate = "@(TempData["FromDate"] as string)";
            var toDate = "@(TempData["ToDate"] as string)";

            var Givenstart = new Date(fromDate);
            var strt = Givenstart.toDateString();
            var givenend = new Date(toDate);
            var end = givenend.toDateString();
            var dateon = new Date(dtOn);
            var dteon = dateon.toDateString();
            //       09            < 10    &&                     10 > 09
            if ((Date.parse(dteon) < Date.parse(strt)) || (Date.parse(end) < Date.parse(dteon))) {
            isValidation = false;
            alert('Date should be in between the From and To dates.');
           
            }

            }
```

If the `DateOn` is not falling between the From and To dates then it will show
`Date should be in between the From and To dates` (alert is coming while using it in Azure even the `dateon` is in between the dates).

Comment: All that parsing and toString-ing is unnecessary, just compare Date objects directly, e.g. `Date.parse(dteon) < Date.parse(strt)` should be just `dateon  < Givenstart `.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the date format and the culture settings.

When you run on your machine you are using you local settings. When on Azure you are running on the default settings of the environment where your code is running.

For example:

- From: 2021-03-08
- To:   2021-07-03

Date checked 2021-04-08

If the date format is YYYY-MM-DD Then date checked is between
If the date format is YYYY-DD-MM Then date checked is not between

(hope I got this right, but you get the idea)

You need to set the culture in your code so that it is not dependent upon where it is running.

Comment: Please tell me "YYYY-DD-MM" is a typo.

Comment: Searching for that date format i google gives 163 000 000 results. So if it is a typo I am not alone.  Some date formats put the day before the month

Comment: You need to update your scarasm–o–meter. I think you'll find [those results](https://www.google.com/search?q=YYYY-DD-MM) are for date formats in general, not  YYYY-DD-MM specifically. :-) See if you can find any support for it among the [date/time formats listed at the CLDR Project](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time-1/date-time-patterns) (which forms the basis of formats supported by *Intl.DateTimeFomat* and various *toLocaleString* formats).

Comment: Sorry about the scarasm. But the basic idea is that some date formats put the day before the month. An easy way to test this is to try a date with the 20th of a month. If the problem is what I think it is your code should fail with an invalid date exception.

Comment: The sarcasm was mine. :-)